# Twitter Search Data for a keywrod

Tags: api, twitter

I'm new to the twitter api and doing an academic project for behavior
analysis for specific set of tweets. I'm interested in getting the
past data for a particular search query ( combination of keywords and
certain constraints ) for a period of at least 2 month and if possible
further.
The Search API lets us retrieve only 1500 tweets. Is that correct?
What can be the possible methods/or already implemented code to
download such a dataset?

I'm sorry if it doesnt look like a coding problem but I'm unable to find any comprehensive resource on web.

Comment: The Twitter search API only retrieves tweets from the past 5-6 days

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out as well .

Answer (score 0):

you can archive them by yourself:

- http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/10_ways_to_archive_your_tweets.php
- or you could make simple script which does the same

and in no-time you will have yourself 20 days worth of tweets.